# Listening to the responses to kaddish before resuming

Tags: kaddish

You are saying Kaddish (either as shaliach tzibbur, or because your are chayiv).
You come to "v'imru amen", and the minyan responds "y'hei shmei rabbah...".

When do you say your own "y'hei shmei rabbah..."? Do you
1 wait until the minyan is finished
2 say it with the minyan
3 wait until a certain point in the minyan's recitation before starting yours
If you have sources for your answers, please provide them here.

Comment: I don't have   the sources offhand but according to almost all opinions you say y'hei shmei rabbah with the congregation and then resume kaddish. There is  one opinion that you say y'hei shmei rabbah out loud after they finish and then resume. I've never seen anyone do the latter practice but perhaps that is because I rarely daven in a shul that does not follow my minhagim

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Aki and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I have seen/heard/experienced all three of these options. The "simultaneous" (my #2) doesn't make sense to me. The purpose of saying Kaddish is to give the others the opp'ty to say Y'hei shmei. So one should stop and listen to that. (Similar to Borchu. We call on minyan to bless HKBH, then we echo that same bracha.) No?